# What is .on function of socket in tcp connection in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp

I have a quick question. Can anyone explain this

```
socket.on("message",function(message){})
```

I am trying to connect to TCP server on node.js

```
server.on('connection',function(socket){
        socket.on('message',function(message){
                console.log("got the message");
                socket.sendEndMessage("hello");
            }
        );
    } );
```

I need to know when `socket.on("message",function(message){})` will be called.

Answer (score 2):

socket.on("message",function(message){}) will be called when a socket connected to the server emits a 'message' event:

```
socket.emit('message', { /* an object to be sent */ });
```

Using socket.on method, allows you to manage how a custom or built-in received message event will be handled. If you're sending different kind of messages through the server, lets say, requestsStats and requestUsersList message types, you'll be emitting messages like

```
socket.emit('requestStats', { filter: statsFilter });
socket.emit('requestUsersList', { filter: userAccessLevel });
```

you'll need to process them on the server (or clients) using:

```
socket.on('requestStats', function(message){ // process message content });
```

and

```
socket.on('requestUsersList', function(message) { // process message content });
```

Basically, you can define custom events/messages to be sent through web sockets.

Comment: thanks a lot. but how can i emit the event from a client.my client can be like c++ socket.

Comment: I haven't need to implement sockets using c++. If you're using socket.io, theres a c++ library: http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-cpp/
In that case, you can send messages using _io->socket()->emit("custom_event",msg);

Comment: yes thanks. i have to use c# library may be (https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet)

Comment: that's right! In that page, there's an example on how to emit custom messages/events.